# Average of numbers input from a text file

Tags: python, file-io

I am trying to find the mean of numbers in a list.  I get the list from a .txt file and then put it through my function.

```
def find_mean(list):
 sumofnums = sum(list)
 avgofnums= sumofnums/len(list)
 print(avgofnums)



def get_numbers_from_file(file_name):
 file = open(file_name, "r")
 strnumbers = file.read().split()
 int_strnumbers = [int(i) for i in strnumbers
 return (int, int_strnumbers)



mylist = get_numbers_from_file(input("Enter file name"))
print(find_mean(mylist))
```

However, I get the operand type error i.e it says the file is returned as a list of strings not ints.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:/Users/andrewr/Desktop/Mean_Module.py", line 15, in <module>
  print(find_mean(mylist))
 File "C:/Users/andrewr/Desktop/Mean_Module.py", line 3, in find_mean
  sumofnums = sum(list)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'type'
```

I thought I solved this problem by changing strnumbers to int_strnumbers.

Please help can anyone help me?

Comment: and you missed a `]` line 11

Comment: You can just use `statistics.mean` instead of your own average function.

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
return (int, int_strnumbers)
```

should just be

```
return int_strnumbers
```

However rather than reading the file line-by-line like this, I'd suggest you use `numpy` which will be much faster. For example reading the file into an array would be

```
numpy.genfromtxt(file_name, delimeter=' ')
```

Then to compute the average you use `numpy.average`

```
mean = numpy.average(numpy.genfromtxt(file_name, delimeter=' '))
```